# Projective superspace: why extra bosonic coordinates

Tags: string-theory, supersymmetry, superspace-formalism, sigma-models

I'm studying the projective superspace formalism for N = 4 supersymmetric $\sigma$-models in two dimensions. My question is: why do we need the extra bosonic coordinates for the manifest action?

I can see that the action (with $\sigma$ the worldsheet coordinates and $\theta$ the fermionic coordinates),

$$S = \int\mathrm{d}^{2}\sigma\mathrm{d}^{8}\theta \mathcal{L},$$

would have a Lagrangian with negative mass dimension since $[\mathrm{d}\sigma]=-1$ and $[\mathrm{d}\theta]=+1/2$ so $[\mathcal{L}]=-2$ and this would be the reason to introduce (two) extra bosonic coordinates in the superspace such that the Lagrangian would become dimensionless.

But what's wrong with a Lagrangian with negative mass dimension in this very abstract superspace? If we would reduce to normal space then there wouldn't be a problem I guess?

Comment: Just for curiosity, can you tell me what references are you following? Thanks.

Comment: Mainly [arXiv:1207.1241](http://arxiv.org/abs/1207.1241) and old ones like http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0370269388908593 and http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0550321384905923. After some more thinking about it, I guess the main thing is that you want to describe the $\sigma$-model with your Lagrangian (just like in the N = (2,2) case where the Lagrangian is the generalised Kahler potential from which you can derive the metric and b-field). And constructing a consistent N = (4,4) Lagrangian with $[\mathcal{L}]$=-2 will be very hard I guess...